# Como faço para Depurar Scripts BASH?

Tags: linux, shell, bash, debug

Como posso Depurar Scripts bash ? No *DOS* da Microsoft posso usar o @echo ON e @echo OFF. Gostaria de usar algo análogo no Linux.

Answer (score 10):

Use o seguinte:

```
sh -x script [arg1 ...]
bash -x script [arg1 ...]
```

Isto permite fazer um **trace** do que está sendo executado.

Outra opção util é **-n** que significa **no execution** e **-v** que significa **verbose mode**. É util combinar estes parametros para facilitar ainda mais seu DEBUG da shell bash quando você invoca pelo prompt.

Se desejar controlar o **trace** de dentro do Script em *blocos específicos de código* use:

```
set -x
```

para **ligar o trace**. Para **desligar o trace** use:

```
set +x
```

Comment: @bmkrio,  O que pode ajudar também é a opção `set -v / +v` , ele exibe o código antes de executar sem o parse (código original).

Comment: Uma boa ajuda na depuração é usar o shellcheck.